# Verification of a Bayes Theorem related problem

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem

This was an assignment problem given to me by the professor. I have did it (not sure if its correct). My answer is around $2/10^{12}$. I fear this is wrong. Can someone try this and verify if possible.

[image]

I don't know if my understanding is correct. But this is what I did:

Since the 2 tests $T_1$ and $T_2$ are independent, we can write as below (C stands for cancer and C' for not cancer):

$P(C|T_1) = \frac{P(C)P(T_1|C)}{P(C)P(T_1|C)+P(C')P(T_1|C')}$

$P(C|T_2) = \frac{P(C)P(T_2|C)}{P(C)P(T_2|C)+P(C')P(T_2|C')}$

And

$P(C) = 1/10^6$

$P(C') = 1 - 1/10^6$

$P(T_1|C) = 0.01\%$

$P(T_2|C) = 1\%$

$P(T_1|C') = 0.1\%$

$P(T_2|C') = 0.05\%$

The final probability is the product $P(C|T_1).P(C|T_2) = 2/10^5 \times 1/10^7 = 2/10^{12} $

Comment: Yes I will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question's definitions of "false positive rate" and "false negative rate" look wrong and misleading to me.

The [false positive rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_positive_rate) should be the proportion of people actually without cancer who give a false positive result on the test.  Similarly the false negative rate should be the proportion of people actually with cancer who give a false negative on the test.

Imagine there were `10,000,000,000,000` people (many times the world population).  Then I suspect the numbers could be

```
                                total            cancer          no cancer
Population               10,000,000,000,000   10,000,000     9,999,990,000,000 
Positive on first test       10,009,989,000    9,999,000         9,999,990,000 
Positive on both tests           14,899,005    9,899,010             4,999,995
```

though you should check these are consistent with the stated false positive and false negative rates.

If so, then looking at the bottom row suggests that the proportion of those testing positive twice who actually have cancer would be about $66.4\%$.

Comment: I think you want $P(C|(T_1\cap T_2))$ (cancer given both tests 1 and 2 are positive).  I came out with a result similar to Henry's.  Also I agree with Henry that the definition of false positive (and negative) is unusual.  Your false positive seems to be P(not cancer | test 1 positive).  Usually a false positive rate would be given as P(test 1 positive |not cancer).  These may give very different results.

Comment: Sorry for asking this question, but where did you got 10,009,989,000 from in total 'Positive on first test', that must be 0.1% of $10^{13}$ right.

Comment: In terms of what you have written, I would have thought you should be trying to calculate $P(C|T_1,T_2) = \dfrac{P(C)P(T_1|C)P(T_2|C)}{P(C)P(T_1|C)P(T_2|C)+P(C')P(T_1|C')P(T_2|C')}$ assuming the independence of $T_1$ and $T_2$

Comment: `10,009,989,000 = 9,999,000 + 9,999,990,000` with the right hand side numbers based on the false negative and false positive rates respectively